# How to check if all the server listed is actually being used when running a build using distcc

Tags: distcc

I'm first time using distcc and have gone through the Readme.

To setup I have three Ubuntu Servers:
Master and Client:

As per the readme it sound like we need to install them on all theree machines. which i have completed.
https://github.com/distcc/distcc/blob/master/INSTALL

Ran the command on all three servers:

sudo apt-get install gcc make python3 python3-dev libiberty-dev

./autogen.sh
./configure
make install

They completed without any errors.

Create ssh keys across the three machines and added then to the authorized host section.
Did a ssh and confirmed they are able to login from the master to the Agent systems without any password

Now from the Master Server i ran the below pointing two the two clients:

```
Export DISTCC_POTENTIAL_HOSTS='localhost 172.31.33.11 172.31.37.109'
```

Created a hello world make file:

```
    #.DEFAULT_GOAL := generate
    .PHONY: all say_hello generate clean

    all: say_hello generate

    say_hello:
            @echo "Hello World"

    generate:
            @echo "Creating empty text files..."
            touch file-{1..10}.txt

    clean:
            @echo "Cleaning up....."
            rm -f *.txt
```

Ran a build using the below command

```
 make
 Hello World
 Creating empty text files...
 touch file-{1..10}.txt
 root@ip-172-31-24-96:/data/helloworls#
```

So here it does look to have worked as expected.

Ran the command as specified in the documentation:

```
pump make -j40 CC="distcc gcc" --debug
__________Using distcc-pump from /usr/local/bin
__________Found 1 available distcc servers
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File 'all' does not exist.
   File 'say_hello' does not exist.
  Must remake target 'say_hello'.
   File 'generate' does not exist.
  Must remake target 'generate'.
Hello World
Creating empty text files...
touch file-{1..10}.txt
 File 'all' does not exist.
 File 'all' does not exist.
Must remake target 'all'.
Successfully remade target file 'all'.
__________Shutting down distcc-pump include server
root@ip-172-31-24-96:/data/helloworls# ls
Makefile  file-{1..10}.txt
root@ip-172-31-24-96:/data/helloworls#
```

Question:

```
1> How do we really know that the two client servers have been used during this build
2> Is setting the client servers same as that of the master, If no is there a difference
3> How do we see the UI distcc Monitor
4> How can i join a range of machines which does not have DistCC installed
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To monitor distcc, you can use `distccmon-text` on the client that is initiating the build. This will output the current status of the jobs in distcc.

To monitor permanently you can use `watch -n 1 distccmon-text` to get the status updated every second.

I haven't used the gui application `distccmon` myself. But I've seen screenshots. That should be an alternative as well, if you have a GUI available on that system.